# How can I make my program faster?

Tags: c++, performance

Today I'm working on making my program faster. This program scans in a 100,000 fake social security numbers, first names, last names and gpa's. My professor has started talking about pointer's, referencing and dereferencing and has said that using these can help speed a program up by passing addresses. My explanation probably sucks because I am not really understanding the topics in class, so while you guys help me out I will be reading in my book for chapter 9 on call by value and call by reference. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

struct nameType{
   string ssno;
   string fName;
   string lName;
   double gpa;
};

int load(istream &in,nameType []);

void shellsort(nameType [],int);

void exchange(nameType &, nameType &);

void print(ostream &out,nameType [],int);

int main(void)
{
   ifstream in;
   ofstream out;

   char infile[40],outfile[40];
   nameType name[100000];
   clock_t start, stop;
   double secl=0;
   double secs=0;
   double secp=0;
   double total=0;
   int n;

   cout << "Please enter the input data file name(NO SPACES): ";
   cin >> infile;

   in.open(infile);
   if(in.fail()) {
      cerr<<"problem input file\n"<<endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   cout << "Please enter the output data file name(NO SPACES): ";
   cin >> outfile;

   out.open(outfile);
   if(out.fail()) {
      cerr<<"problem output file\n"<<endl;
      exit(1);
   }

   start = clock();
   n = load(in,name);
   stop = clock();
   secl = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   cout << "Load Time: " << secl << endl;

   start = clock();
   shellsort(name,n);
   stop = clock();
   secs = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   cout << "Sort Time: " << secs << endl;

   start = clock();
   print(out,name,n);
   stop = clock();
   secp = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   cout << "Print Time: " << secp << endl;

   total = secl + secs + secp;
   cout << "Total Time: " << total << endl;

   in.close();
   out.close();

   return 0;
}

int load(istream &in,nameType name[])
{
   int n=0;

   in >> name[n].ssno >> name[n].fName >> name[n].lName >> name[n].gpa;
   while(!in.eof()){
      n++;
      in >> name[n].ssno >> name[n].fName >> name[n].lName >> name[n].gpa;
   }
   return n;
}

void shellsort(nameType name[],int n)
{
   int gap = n/2;
   bool passOk;
   while(gap>0){
      passOk=true;
      for(int i=0; i<n-gap; i++){
         if(name[i].lName>name[i+gap].lName){
            exchange(name[i],name[i+gap]);
            passOk=false;
         }
         else if(name[i].lName == name[i+gap].lName && name[i].fName > name[i+gap].fName){
            exchange(name[i],name[i+gap]);
            passOk=false;
         }
      }
      if(passOk){
         gap/=2;
      }
   }
}

void exchange(nameType &a, nameType &b)
{
   nameType temp;
   temp = a;
   a = b;
   b = temp;
}

void print(ostream &out,nameType name[],int n)
{
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      out << name[i].ssno << " " <<  name[i].fName << " " << name[i].lName << " " << name[i].gpa << endl;
   }
   out << endl;
}
```

**Exact assignment details--- I'm on bullet number 5---**

**Efficiency - time and space**

Time and space are always issues to consider when writing programs.

In this assignment, you will be modifying the sort_v4.cpp program created in the first programming assignment. In that assignment, you were required to process an array of integers. Let's update the program with several items:

Build a structure containing an social security number, first name, last name, and a GPA.
The new sort technique that uses the gap concept as described in class that sorts the information in ascending order based on the last name (if last names are the same then the first names need to be checked).  The sort technique is know as shell sort.
Improve the efficiency - time and space as described below.

Each struct element contained an ID, first name, last name and gpa. Suppose you had to process 100,000 students. The program is inefficient for two reasons

Space issue: if social security number takes up 12 characters, first and last take up 20 characters each, and the gpa as a double takes up 8 bytes then the main array of structure elements consumes (12+20+20+8)*100000 bytes of memory. This may be OK if we load up 100,000 names.   But if the average number of students we process is <50,000, then there is a considerable amount of wasted memory.
Time issue: When you exchange two elements that are out of order, 60 bytes are moved around 3 times. Total of 180 bytes are moved in memory. Again, inefficient.

As the number of member variables in the struct increase the problem gets worse.

The focus of this assignment is to

Read a file containing the social security number, first, last, and a gpa into an array of structure elements.  Process until EOF.  Each line contains information about one student.  Inside the struct, the elements may be define as char [] or strings.  Do you think it will make a difference in performance if we use char [] vs strings?  Make a prediction.
Dump the array into a file along with timing information.
Try out the new sort technique - sort structure elements based on two items - first and last name.
Time each function to see where the most time is being spent.
Attempt to improve the use of memory by using an array of pointers to the structs.
Attempt to improve the efficiency by making the exchange faster by swapping pointers instead of elements.

With the above list in mind, there will be three possible grades for the assignment.  For a maximum grade of a C - 14/20 points, you must complete the first two bullets.  For a maximum grade of a B - 16/20 points, you must complete the first 4 bullets.  For an A, you must complete all bullets.

I would recommend to start the assignment by implementing what I call a non pointer version.  Define a struct above the main function to hold the items.  The main function should declare the array of struct elements.  Call the load, sort, and print functions as we did in the first assignment making adjustments to accommodate the struct and the new sort technique where there are two items to consider before exchanging two elements.  NOTE: I want to see an exchange function this time.  This will give you a total of 4 functions.  Make sure you follow the guidelines stated in the first programming assignment.

For all that are attempting the A program, make sure you have the basic program for a B completed and tested before continuing.  Make a copy of that program and modify the program as follows:

Change the array of struct elements to an array of pointers to struct elements by placing a * in the definition.
Using new (or malloc), dynamically create space for one structure element just before you read in the values for the members of the struct.
When you exchange two elements, exchange two pointers to struct elements instead of the struct elements themselves.
Take a look at your times for the non-pointer version and the pointer version.  Is there a significant difference?

Following is the information about timing one function.

```
#include<ctime>
//Create a couple variables of clock_t type.
clock_t  start, stop;
start = clock();
load(x, n);   //call a function to perform a task
stop = clock();
cout << "load time: " << (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
```

The function clock() returns the number of cpu clock cycles that have occurred since the program started.  Ideally, start in the above code should be 0.  To be able to make some sense of how much time a function takes, you have to convert the elapsed time into seconds.  This is accomplished by taking the difference between start and stop, typecasting, then dividing by the system defined CLOCKS_PER_SEC.  On linus public (or an alien ware machine in the lab) is 1,000,000.  Also see class notes on the topic.  The following is an example of what should appear at the end of the sorted data.

load time: 0.05
sort time: 2.36
print time: 0.01
Total Run time: 2.42

The Penalty for missing deadline, 1 pt per day for a max of 7 days. Programs will not be accepted 7 days after the deadline.

Comment: Nobody is going to wave a magic wand and make your program faster. Depending on the structure of your input file, shellsort may not be optimal. Use a profiler to see the execution time of each line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look here: [How are arrays passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559896/how-are-arrays-passed)

Arrays are passed as pointers already, and your implementation of std::swap (which you called "exchange") is already passing by reference.  So that is not an issue in your case.  Has your professor complained about your program execution speed?

Comment: Let me paste the exact assignment that was given to us. Maybe this will help my explanation.

Comment: Okay, well in that case, the assignment says: " Attempt to improve the use of memory by using an array of pointers to the structs. Attempt to improve the efficiency by making the exchange faster by swapping pointers instead of elements."
If you look at your algorithm, right now it's using the actual structures.  You want to change it to 
    `void shellsort(nameType* name[],int n)`

An array of pointers to nameTypes instead of an array of nameTypes.
Similarly, you'll need exchange to have a signature of 
    `void exchange(nameType *&a, nameType *&b)`
or similar.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A place that takes a lot of execution time in a program is called a bottleneck.

A common bottleneck is file input and output.  You can make your program faster by reducing or optimizing the bottleneck.

Reading many small pieces of data from a file takes more time than reading one large piece of data.  For example, reading 10 lines of data with one request is more efficient that 10 requests to read one line of data.

Accessing memory is fast, faster than reading from a file.

The general pattern is:
1. Read a lot of data into memory.
2. Process the data.
3. Repeat at 1 as necessary.

So, you could use the "block" read command, `istream::read` into an array of bytes.  Load a string with a line of data from the array of bytes and process the line.  Repeat loading from the array until you run out and then reload from the file.